# Not able to view text from guest book I created?

Tags: php, invisible

I created a Guestbook for a website with 3 different php pages I am not able to view the text after someone submits a comment on the guestbook.. here is the coding for each

---

**guestbook.php**

---

```
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
body {
    background-color: #333333;
}
a:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
<body bgcolor="#333333" text="#FFFFFF" link="#FFFFFF" vlink="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFFFF">    <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" >
<tr>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="addguestbook.php">
<td>
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" >
<tr>
<td width="117">Name</td>
<td width="14">:</td>
<td width="357"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="40" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="40" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Comment</td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="  Sign  " /> <input type="reset"      name="Submit2" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

**adressbook.php**

---

```
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    color: #FFF;
}
body {
    background-color: #333333;
}
a:link {
    color: #FFF;
}
a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
}
a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
a:active {
    color: #FFF;
}
</style>
<body bgcolor="#333333" text="#FFF" link="#FFF" vlink="#FFF" alink="#FFF"><?php
$host="*********"; // Host name 
$username="***********"; // Mysql username 
$password="***********!"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="***********"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="guestbook"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$datetime=date("y-m-d h:i:s"); //date time

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name, email, comment, datetime)VALUES('$name', '$email',     '$comment', '$datetime')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//check if query successful 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";

}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

---

**viewguestbook.php**

---

```
<?php

$host="*********"; // Host name 
$username="******"; // Mysql username 
$password="*****!"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="******"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="guestbook"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    color: #FFF;
}
body {
    background-color: #666;
}
a:link {
    color: #FFF;
}
a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
}
a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
a:active {
    color: #FFF;
}
</style>


<table width="400" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" >
<tr>
<td><table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" >
<tr>
  <td width="117">Name</td>
  <td width="14">:</td>
  <td width="357"><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top">Comment</td>
  <td valign="top">:</td>
  <td><? echo $rows['comment']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Date/Time </td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>
  <?php
}
mysql_close(); //close database
?>
</p>
<p>&nbsp; </p>
```

---

If anyone could help please?
Also I the order of the comments are showing ascending I would like to show them descending?

Comment: **Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What error message you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

To change it to descending change.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
```

to

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM guestbook ORDER BY datetime DESC";
```

---

I'm not sure what you mean by "I am not able to view the text". Does this mean your guestbook php page shows no entries, or the database is blank?

I'm not sure why you did `$tbl_name = "guestbook";` but that just confuses things. Also your spaces are all over the place so I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Try changing...

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name, email, comment, datetime)VALUES('$name', '$email',     '$comment', '$datetime')";
```

into

```
$sql="INSERT INTO guestbook (name, email, comment, datetime) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$comment', '$datetime')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//change this line as

while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ .. }


mysql_fetch_array -- will always returns the indexed array.

//http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php
```